# Is this asbestos insulation?

Tags: insulation, asbestos

I was removing some panels in the garage of the house that I rent, and found one wall filled with insulation, at first I thought of mineral wool but as it all fell in crumbles I'm afraid it might be Asbestos insulation. Will take a sample to the lab but would like to know your opinion in the meantime.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a question... did you have it tested and did it end up being an asbestos product?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like fiberglass or rockwool(this is not asbestos). Safest to have it tested but you should seal off the space and not enter it until you know. I've two Aunts who died from indirect contact with asbestos.

Even if it is fiberglass you should be wearing a filter mask as it is essentially spun silica (glass) and the particles can cause silicosis (and skin irritation).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. Usually asbestos insulation is "fibrosis" and easily floats and flies through the air...this looks "foam-like", but you're smart to have it tested. (We found asbestos in mastic, so you never know.)

Comment: Fibrosis is a medical condition, perhaps you mean it is fibrous.

Comment: @PJTraill Good call. I learned something already today.

Answer (score 0):

It is not asbestos. My father-in-law and I insulated his attic with that stuff  about 50 years ago, when I was young and dumb. I itched for days and we did the work in July.They called it pouring wool and it came in bags.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

After finding that insulation I went on a asbestos hunt and easily found some tape around the furnace ducts, so far only outside the duct. Is it of any concern if it's not disturbed?

[image]

Comment: That stuff on the duct work looks like and may be asbestos. It was used years ago to seal and quiet duct work. If it were mine I would get a can of spray paint and cover it (encapsulate it). If it is covering a hole in the duct and has air moving over it I would have it checked  by professionals who deal in asbestos just to be safe